# ReactNative - IOS Crash - Symbolicated crash report -

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Im am brushing up my first ReactNative IOS app. With XCode and the device simulators, everything works fine. But when I install the app on my Iphone4S (release mode, Saved for development deployment) it crashes with a very opaque crash report (even once it is symbolicated...).

```
Incident Identifier: 4F2E39E3-04AA-464F-8E8A-A3E64DAB967C
CrashReporter Key:   acfbbf1516e80394d2495007d52f7c5828dd89ba
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:             KinderApp Release [217]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/E5AA4CFF-F0CB-4FD6-819A-0ECF2FE0BC5B/KinderApp Release.app/KinderApp Release
Identifier:          io.deux.KinderApp
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-03-23 17:42:45.407 +0100
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.2 (11D257)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2e1edf7e __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3899ecca objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2e1edec0 +[NSException raise:format:] + 100
3   KinderApp Release               0x000ce6da __hidden#7134_ (__hidden#7589_:133)
4   KinderApp Release               0x000e5ae8 __hidden#9463_ (__hidden#9656_:491)
5   KinderApp Release               0x000e3a74 __hidden#9411_ (__hidden#9656_:112)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x38e8682e _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 6
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x38e8681a _dispatch_client_callout + 18
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x38e86772 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$up + 250
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2e1b889c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 4
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2e1b7170 __CFRunLoopRun + 1296
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2e121eba CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2e121c9e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
13  GraphicsServices                0x3302765e GSEventRunModal + 134
14  UIKit                           0x30a6e148 UIApplicationMain + 1132
15  KinderApp Release               0x00089e82 main (__hidden#9_:16)
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x38eabab2 tlv_initializer + 2


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38f611f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38fcb792 pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38f11fd8 abort + 72
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38240cd2 abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x382596e0 default_terminate_handler() + 248
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3899ef62 _objc_terminate() + 190
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x382571c4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38256a18 __cxa_throw + 112
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3899ed9e objc_exception_throw + 246
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2e1edec0 +[NSException raise:format:] + 100
10  KinderApp Release               0x000ce6da __hidden#7134_ (__hidden#7589_:133)
11  KinderApp Release               0x000e5ae8 __hidden#9463_ (__hidden#9656_:491)
12  KinderApp Release               0x000e3a74 __hidden#9411_ (__hidden#9656_:112)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x38e86830 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x38e8681c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x38e86772 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$up + 250
16  CoreFoundation                  0x2e1b889c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 4
17  CoreFoundation                  0x2e1b7170 __CFRunLoopRun + 1296
18  CoreFoundation                  0x2e121eba CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
19  CoreFoundation                  0x2e121c9e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
20  GraphicsServices                0x3302765e GSEventRunModal + 134
21  UIKit                           0x30a6e148 UIApplicationMain + 1132
22  KinderApp Release               0x00089e82 main (__hidden#9_:16)
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x38eabab4 start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38f4e808 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x38e9ade8 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x38e89f6e _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 34

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38f61c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38fc8bda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38fc8a94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38f4eaa8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x38e99f74 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 172
2   libxpc.dylib                    0x38fd90ae xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 150
3   libsystem_network.dylib         0x38fa2a08 net_helper_interface_is_cellular + 180
4   libsystem_network.dylib         0x38f9fb2e tcp_connection_is_cellular + 90
5   CFNetwork                       0x2dddba8a SocketStream::socketCallbackConnectLocked(SocketStreamSignalHolder*, void const*) + 118
6   CFNetwork                       0x2dddb9d0 SocketStream::socketCallback(__CFSocket*, unsigned long, __CFData const*, void const*) + 88
7   CFNetwork                       0x2dddb942 SocketStream::_SocketCallBack_stream(__CFSocket*, unsigned long, __CFData const*, void const*, void*) + 54
8   CoreFoundation                  0x2e1bb2f0 __CFSocketPerformV0 + 368
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2e1b9208 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2e1b86d6 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 202
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2e1b6eca __CFRunLoopRun + 618
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2e121eba CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2e121c9e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
14  Foundation                      0x2eb62082 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 314
15  Foundation                      0x2ebd7a5a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38fca916 _pthread_body + 138
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38fca886 _pthread_start + 98
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38fc8aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38f61c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38fc8bda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38fc8a94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38f61434 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2e1bc708 __CFSocketManager + 480
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38fca916 _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38fca886 _pthread_start + 98
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38fc8aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00002060
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3acc918c      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x27d80004
    r8: 0x155abe60    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x155b17c0     r11: 0x155b22e0
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x27d7fff8      lr: 0x38fcb797      pc: 0x38f611f0
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

**EDIT :** In the meantimes, I was able to reproduce the bug on Xcode and to get a more explicit error log.

The error comes when I comment this line in AppDelegate.m:

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

and that I uncomment this line:

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

Here is the console log:

```
2016-03-25 14:59:06.078 [error][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] Unable to execute JS call: __fbBatchedBridge is undefined
2016-03-25 14:59:06.083 KinderApp Release[5500:23084] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unable to execute JS call: __fbBatchedBridge is undefined', reason: 'Unable to execute JS call: __fbBatchedBridge is undefined'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01645a14 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00894e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0164593d +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
    3   KinderApp Release                   0x0014b71b RCTFatal + 460
    4   KinderApp Release                   0x0016acf2 __69-[RCTBatchedBridge _actuallyInvokeAndProcessModule:method:arguments:]_block_invoke + 54
    5   KinderApp Release                   0x00165347 __52-[RCTJSCExecutor _executeJSCall:arguments:callback:]_block_invoke + 1506
    6   KinderApp Release                   0x00165a11 -[RCTJSCExecutor executeBlockOnJavaScriptQueue:] + 191
    7   KinderApp Release                   0x00164d01 -[RCTJSCExecutor _executeJSCall:arguments:callback:] + 185
    8   KinderApp Release                   0x00164b31 -[RCTJSCExecutor callFunctionOnModule:method:arguments:callback:] + 181
    9   KinderApp Release                   0x0016ac7b -[RCTBatchedBridge _actuallyInvokeAndProcessModule:method:arguments:] + 190
    10  KinderApp Release                   0x0016a1bb __39-[RCTBatchedBridge enqueueJSCall:args:]_block_invoke_2 + 144
    11  KinderApp Release                   0x0016913b __36-[RCTBatchedBridge didFinishLoading]_block_invoke + 158
    12  KinderApp Release                   0x00165a11 -[RCTJSCExecutor executeBlockOnJavaScriptQueue:] + 191
    13  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x008a9059 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    14  Foundation                          0x004a30d8 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 323
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0155f6ff __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0155538b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x015547a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x015540e6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x01553efb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    20  KinderApp Release                   0x00163b93 +[RCTJSCExecutor runRunLoopThread] + 318
    21  Foundation                          0x004a59ba -[NSThread main] + 76
    22  Foundation                          0x0055a1cc __NSThread__start__ + 1346
    23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x04e5e794 _pthread_body + 138
    24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x04e5e70a _pthread_body + 0
    25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x04e5bfa6 thread_start + 34
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try in Xcode > Window > Devices and look at the Device log to see if anything stands out, is your provisions profile okay etc?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is already the symbolicated crash log, extracted from the devices logs with the dSym file...
And yes, my provision profile is okay...